# Progressdialog won't show up

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

I want to show this dialog, while the thread tries to build up a connection, but the dialog will not show up when I press the button which starts this method.

```
public void add_mpd(View view) {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Trying to connect...");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String child;
                EditText new_mpd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_mpd);
                child = new_mpd.getText().toString();
                mpd = new MPD(child);
                children.get(1).add(child);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MPDConnectionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    ).start();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not show up because the (blocking) work is done in another thread. That means, the `start()`-method of the `Thread`-class will not block.

Ergo, you show the Dialog, the Thread is started and the dialog is immediately dismissed (and therefore closed).

Put the call to `dismiss()` at the end of your `run()`-method and it should work just fine.

---

The above might be working for you, but you should not use the `Thread`-class directly. There are wrappers around it which are way more comfortable to use.

In Android, if you want to do long-term work off the UI-Thread, you should use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I second Lukas on his answer.

Comment: @user1629115 as I mentioned in the update of my answer, you'll probably want to use `AsyncTask` for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly, to build up on what Lukas said, you can look at this example.

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog

```
public class ProgressDialogExample extends Activity implements Runnable {

    private String pi_string;
    private TextView tv;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.main);
            tv.setText("Press any key to start calculation");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Calculating Pi", true,
                            false);

            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();

            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void run() {
            pi_string = Pi.computePi(800).toString();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    tv.setText(pi_string);

            }
    };
```

}